# Datatransfer in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom-events

I am implementing dragging an image from thumbnail and dropping into a canvas and draw it.

I have used `datatransfer.setdata()` during the event `ondragstart` and `datatransfer.getdata()` on event `ondrop`. It is working perfectly in Firefox, but doesn't work in Chrome. I have come to know that in Chrome datatransfer is not supported. So, what can be a good solution, that should be cross browser compatible too!

```
function dragIt(event) {
event.dataTransfer.setData("URL", event.target.id)
};

function dropIt(event) {
  var theData = new Image();
  theData = event.dataTransfer.getData("URL");
  dt = document.getElementById(theData);
  event.preventDefault();
  var ctx = this.getContext('2d');
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,this.width,this.height);
  ctx.drawImage(dt, 0, 0);      
};

var out = document.getElementById('out');
        var Can1 = document.createElement("canvas");
        Can1.height="100";
        Can1.width="100";
        Can1.style.cssText = 'position:relative; top:5px;left:500px;border:2px  solid black;'  
        Can1.ondragover = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        };
        Can1.ondrop = dropIt;  
        out.appendChild(Can1);
```

Comment: Actually, dataTransfer has worked in Chrome for years. You're not using a valid MIME type in `event.dataTransfer.setData()`. Chrome used to have issues handling MIME types other than `text/plain` and `text/uri-list`, but that was fixed in version 19.

Comment: It is certainly not working for us in Chrome 24, or Chrome 22 a colleague tells me.  If we work out a solution we'll be sure to post it here.

Answer (score 1):

I know the proverbial horse has probably bolted on this question but I've also just noticed this problem in Chrome with getData/setData.  For me, it works *only* if you use "text" or "text/plain" as the format for the data, and everything else fails with `event.dataTransfer.getData(format)` returning `undefined`.

In Chrome's Developer Tools, you can inspect the `event.dataTransfer.types` property to see which values are accepted for the "format" parameter to the getData/setData functions.

Therefore changing "URL" to "text" may solve the problem in this case.  Unfortunately, I've so far failed to find any information on why Chrome's chosen to implement only these formats.

Comment: I've also just run into this problem.  Using "text" or "text/plain" isn't working for me.  Works fine in Firefox.

Comment: Chromium also has problems handling `text/uri-list` - when transferring a list of uris, they should be separated by `\n`. But Chrome strips away the newlines, so the target just receives one long string of all the uris joined together. This bug was reported in 2013 (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=239745), and 7 years on it is still annoying developers!